# Possible bug with the Clean-Up site. Recieved a merged question in my allocation

Tags: bug, cleanup

I'm not sure if I'm right about this but I recieved this question in my allocation for the clean-up: [VGA for external monitor is flickering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6075/vga-for-external-monitor-is-flickering)

This question has already been merged with [GMA 5700 MHD Dell Vostro 3300 externel vga monitor is flickering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7700/gma-5700-mhd-dell-vostro-3300-externel-vga-monitor-is-flickering)

So presumably it is already closed? There are no answers and it can't be answered as the space to enter answers has been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug.

It actually wasn't closed, because merging != closing (for some reason).

I just closed it for you.